# 2 dimensional Array and JApplet: button visibility and label change

Tags: java, arrays, button, applet, visibility

I am having 2 somewhat straightforward problems:

1) I am trying to set `btns[0][0]` (row 0, column 0) to be the only visible button on my 00-99 button grid, and after I press the button, the ones touching it become visible and the process continues until all buttons are visible.

2) After each button is pressed, the button (that is pressed, not every button) changes it's number label into a smiley face, `setLabel(":)")`.

```
public class Project5 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;
    Container contentPane;
    JButton[][] btns = new JButton[10][10];
    int clicks = 0;

    public void init() {

        setSize(600, 600);
        contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 


        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(10,10,0,4);
        contentPane.setLayout(grid);
        clicks = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                btns[i][j] = new JButton();                
                button = new JButton(""+i+j);
                button.addActionListener(this);
                contentPane.add(button);
                //button.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        btns[0][0].setVisible(true);

        String button_label = e.getActionCommand();

        int row = Character.getNumericValue(button_label.charAt(0));
        int column = Character.getNumericValue(button_label.charAt(1));          


        clicks++;

        if (clicks % 5 == 0) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        } else if (clicks % 5 == 1) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (clicks % 5 == 2) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (clicks % 5 == 3) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (clicks % 5 == 4) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);          
        }

    }

    public void checkDone() {
        //if all buttons visible, change contentPane color to black.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button visibility problem stems from the fact that you are creating two buttons in your loop.
You're putting one of them in your array, and doing all your work on the other one.

Instead of this

```
btns[i][j] = new JButton();                
button = new JButton(""+i+j);
```

you want to do this

```
button = new JButton(""+i+j);  
btns[i][j] = button;
```

---

Regarding your `actionPerformed()` method, whenever a button is clicked, it will create an `ActionEvent` and 'fire' it at its listeners. This means that it will go through all of those listeners and call `actionPerformed()` on each one.  Whenever a listener is called, the event which is passed to it has a special `Object` inside it called the **source** (i.e. whatever the thing was which fired the event).

In your case, the source will be the button that was clicked, and you can get the button which was clicked, and obtain its label text like this:

```
    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String label = button.getText();
    button.setText(":)");
```

Then all you'll need to do is parse `label` to get the coordinates of the clicked button.
Once you have the coordinates, you can figure out the neighbors and set them to visible.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
public class Project5 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    JButton[][] btns = new JButton[10][10];
    int clicks = 0;
    static Map<Integer, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();

    public void init() {

        colors.put(0, Color.PINK);
        colors.put(1, Color.GREEN);
        colors.put(2, Color.BLUE);
        colors.put(3, Color.YELLOW);
        colors.put(4, Color.RED);

        setSize(600, 600);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 0, 4));

        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
                JButton button = new JButton(""+i+j);
                button.addActionListener(this);
                button.setVisible(false);
                btns[i][j] = button;
                contentPane.add(button);
            }
        }
        btns[0][0].setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String text = source.getText();
        if (text.equals(":)"))
            return;
        int row = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(0, 1));
        int col = Integer.valueOf(text.substring(1, 2));    
        try {
            btns[row][col+1].setVisible(true);
            btns[row+1][col].setVisible(true);
            btns[row][col-1].setVisible(true);
            btns[row-1][col].setVisible(true);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e2) {}
        source.setText(":)");

        contentPane.setBackground(colors.get(clicks++%5));
    }

    public void checkDone() {

        // if all buttons visible, change contentPane color to black.
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I put your colors in a `Map`, makes it easier to manage later on.
- I changed some field definitions.
- I assumed that if the user clicks a button that was already clicked, nothing happens.
- I took an ill-advised shortcut with the `try-catch` block to ignore `ArrayOutOfBounds` exceptions for buttons on the edges. Consider doing real checks for their position instead and setting only the correct buttons to visible.
- I identified the location of the source button by its label. While fine if all the buttons have 2 digits of row-column, it is safer to iterate through the array and find the button with `btns[i][j].equals(source)` and read the position this way.